# Pidgin frequently disconnects with the message "write error"

Tags: connection, gnome3, pidgin, ms-office-communicator

**Pidgin 2.10.11-7.el7 (libpurple 2.10.11)**

**Office Communicator protocol**

**GNOME 3**

**CentOS 7**

Pidgin frequently disconnects.

On the login screen it will print out "write error"

I looked in my home directory/.purple and found no logs about how pidgin is failing. Where I can go for more error informaiton.

Any ideas about what this is about and how to fix it?